# How to add span inside a span using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of Strings(say names) in javascript. I want to add the values from this array to my dropdown list.
The dropdown list code is like :

```
<span id="ddcl-pFilterSelect" class="ui-dropdownchecklist ui-dropdownchecklist-selector-wrapper ui-widget" style="display: inline-block; cursor: default; overflow: hidden;">
  <span class="dropdownChecklistAllBack" style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" tabindex="0">
    <span class="ui-dropdownchecklist-text" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;" title="default">default
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Currently this dropdown list only displays a single value : default.
I want to display values from the string names in this dropdown menu.
Please suggest how can I do it using JQuery. I tried many ways but to no avail.

Comment: Dropdown list built from spans? :/

Comment: "I tried many ways..." Show them.

Comment: span as dropdown list? use select

Comment: `$('#ddcl-pFilterSelect  .dropdownChecklistAllBack').append('<span>Your Value</span>')`

Comment: @Sid M or at least an `ul` with `li`s

Comment: @meskobalazs The code is not in my control. It is a dynamically generated list, I have the end result and I need to modify this html.

Comment: It helps if we know what jQuery plugin you are using, since the behavior you are expecting is not native to jQuery.  Are you using [jQuery Dropdown Checklist](https://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn-history/r54/trunk/src/demo.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
    $('.dropdownChecklistAllBack').append('<span class="ui-dropdownchecklist-text" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;" title="default">' + value + '</span>');
});
```

Comment: This is not safe. `value` can be injected with Javascript.

Comment: All values can be injected with javascript, it's his work to check the received value with php (or whatever server side language he is using).

Comment: It's still dangerous. Why don't make use of the `innerText` property of HTMLElement or `.text()` method of jQuery if I remember correctly. That way, the passed value can never be injected as HTML.

Comment: @potasmic HTML and JavaScript can always be changed or injected by the client, no matter what you try to do to prevent it.  Anything passed to the server must be checked in server-side code, there's no harm in doing this on the client side since it's not currently being passed to the server and there's no discussion about this being passed to the server.